# Angular 2 concatenate variable in interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two related objects:

```
itemsObj = {
    'item1' : 'A1',
    'item2' : 'A2',
    'item3'  : 'B',
    'item4'  : 'C',
    'item5'  : 'D'
};
```

And:

```
itemsObj2 = {
    'A1' : 'Very conservative and up',
    'A2' : 'Conservative and up',
    'B'  : 'Balanced and up',
    'C'  : 'Growth and up',
    'D'  : 'Aggressive'
};
```

Interpolating `{{itemsObj.item1}}` will return `A1` and `{{itemsObj2.A1}}` will return `Very conservative and up`.

How to concatenate `itemsObj.item1` with `itemsObj2.A1` to return `Very conservative and up`?

**My attempt:**

`{{itemsObj2.itemsObj.item1}}` but of course this is wrong. So may I know how to concatenate in my case?

Comment: `{{itemsObj2[itemsObj.item1]}}`

Comment: Do you want to display only one value or display them all and have the possibility to loop over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
itemsObj2[itemsObj.item1]    //setting itemsObj.item1's value as itemsObj2's key
```

DEMO:

```js
itemsObj = {
    'item1' : 'A1',
    'item2' : 'A2',
    'item3'  : 'B',
    'item4'  : 'C',
    'item5'  : 'D'
};

itemsObj2 = {
    'A1' : 'Very conservative and up',
    'A2' : 'Conservative and up',
    'B'  : 'Balanced and up',
    'C'  : 'Growth and up',
    'D'  : 'Aggressive'
};

console.log(itemsObj2[itemsObj.item1])
```

Comment: Should be the accepted solution, just for the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public items: string[];

  constructor() {
    const itemsObj = {
      'item1': 'A1',
      'item2': 'A2',
      'item3': 'B',
      'item4': 'C',
      'item5': 'D'
    };

    const itemsObj2 = {
      'A1': 'Very conservative and up',
      'A2': 'Conservative and up',
      'B': 'Balanced and up',
      'C': 'Growth and up',
      'D': 'Aggressive'
    };

    this.items = Object
      .values(itemsObj)
      .map(itemKey => itemsObj2[itemKey]);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
Very conservative and up
Conservative and up
Balanced and up
Growth and up
Aggressive
```

**Stackblitz demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbdfux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Too much for so little. I'd go for Sajeet's solution

Comment: True. But this solution provides a way to loop over it. If OP don't need that fine, otherwise here it is. (I just doubt that with a set of different keys he just want to display one, but maybe)

Comment: I agree, but that's not what he asked. Although it's perfectly valid and working code, you're giving an overkill solution, hence my downvote.

Comment: Wow downvote for 3 lines / valid solution. I personally downvote for wrong or very incomplete solutions with a lack of explanations. Not for valid solutions with demo and all ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: And I downvote sot the solution that isn't best suited for a question isn't a the top of the page. To each his own way of voting.

Comment: Be glad I comment when I downvote instead of complaining, Sajeet got downvoted for no reason (not by me of course)

Comment: Oh and by the way, your solution isn't mandatory to iterate over items. In fact, it's the exact same thing as using an array notation, just with more and not required code.

Comment: @maxime1992. Thanks a lot for the solution. Although I did not need to loop over in my case. Still learnt something new. :)

Comment: "Be glad I comment when I downvote" that's something. "In fact, it's the exact same thing as using an array notation, just with more and not required code" stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to match the key , you can do

```
   <h1> {{itemsObj2[itemsObj.item1]}}</h1>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqrgnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Guys if you're downvoting anyone add the reason

Comment: Those who have upvoted my comment, please go further up and upvote answer  too :P

Comment: Yeah I'm tired of getting downvotes with no explanation, so I only make looooong answers with explanations, so quick downvoters don't even read it (And I upvoted the solution already)